# "The site is experiencing technical difficulties" when clicking Download cart as pdf? (Plugin: WooCommerce Cart to PDF)

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, cart

I use a plugin for Wordpress and Woocommerce that is called "WooCommerce Cart PDF" that have the funcionality that makes shoppers be able to download their cart in my store to a downloadable pdf. The installation works fine, but when I click on the link "Download cart as pdf" in the cart page I get to a blank page that say "The site is experiencing technical difficulties". Everything else on the website is working fine.

Does anybody know what I could do to fix it or how I can proceed in my testing of what could be the source of the error?

I'm running latest versions of the plugin, Wordpress and Woocommerce. Server is using PHP 7.0. I have tried to disable plugins one by one and switched to a default theme.

There is no code to show. The plugin can be downloaded here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-cart-pdf/.

Expected result: a working link that downloads a pdf that includes the products that the shopper have in their cart. Right now only a error is shown.

Comment: Check your server logs and paste the error. Its likely a plugin conflict or a problem with the plugin. Apache its usually in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: The problem is with the wc-cart-pdf plugin. You can check the exact issue but enabling the WP_DEBUG mode, take a look to the step by step guide https://wprepairgigs.com/the-site-is-experiencing-technical-difficulties-error-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have an WP Error.

To get rid of this problem do a change:

1. Open your wp-config.php file
2. Set WP_DEBUG to true.
3. Save the file and check your page where errors are coming.

Now you will have the specific errors such as warnings, or fatal errors or notices.